# Run Maximum Likelihood Estimation MLE based on Kalman filtering

Tags: maximum-likelihood, kalman-filter, optimization

I used an UKF (unscented Kalman filter) with MLE to estimate and identification of a discrete nonlinear state space model with the number of state equal to 8, and 13 parameters of the model.

I used the kalman filter (UKF) directly to approximate the log-likelihood and its gradient.
I succeeded to calculate the  marginal log-likelihood and its gradient based on UKF recursion.

I used the **CG** (**C**onjugate **G**radient) optimization method to estimate the parameters.

The **CG** need the gradient of the objective function, calculated in a recursion way in the Kalman filtering pass.

how can I use it for the **CG**?

**1.** should I run the Kalman filter until he finish (with storing the filtering data), and then create a function with a loop for the gradient which use the filtering data. so I can use it in the **CG** optimization procedure.

**2.** Or

**a**. initialize the Kalman filter with initial guess for the parameters vector $ \theta_0$.

**b**. run the Kalman filter and its derivative (necessary for the calculation of the gradient of the Log-likelihood) every step of the optimization procedure using the last estimated parameters from MLE, to guarantee that the changes in the parameters are propagated through the Kalman filter and its derivative  and thus these changes affect the innovation vector and innovation covariance matrix used for the calculation of the log-likelihood and the gradient used in the **CG** optimization method and so on.

Comment: Would you kindly adopt proper grammar with capital "I", capital letters at the start of the sentence, etc.? The current grammar makes it difficult to understand your text.

Comment: Sorry I am not good in English language, but the letter " i " I mean by it the personal pronoun " I " in all the question. I try to correct the posted question but don't know how I do that.

Comment: I understand that. But you should be able to edit your own post.